# how to go to next element in page with same class name using selenium vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

i have a page opened in selenium vba, and in this page i have a lot of elements with the same class name, and when i get this element with the code: `People = driver.findElementByClass("labelinfo").Text` it returns to me the first element in page, and i want the element number 7, so, i use the code: `driver.findElementsByClassName("labelinfo").Count` and it says the page have 27 elements "labelinfo". So, how i can "walk" element by element using a for loop until it reaches the element number 7?
my code is:

```
    Public Sub AbreELogaNoForum()
    Dim i As Integer, MyPass As String, MyLogin As String, nome As String, data As String, carteira As String, guia As String, test As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
redo:
    MyLogin = Application.InputBox("Por Favor entre com o Login")
    MyPass = Application.InputBox("Por favor entre com a senha")
    If MyLogin = "" Or MyPass = "" Then GoTo redo
    driver.Start "chrome", "http://rda.unimednc.com.br/"
    driver.setImplicitWait 50000

    driver.Open "http://rda.unimednc.com.br/"
    driver.findElementById("login").SendKeys MyLogin
    driver.findElementById("password").SendKeys MyPass
    driver.findElementById("Button_DoLogin").Click

    test = 7
    Range("B1").Select
    For i = 1 To 10
    MsgBox ("Esperando")
    'nome = driver.findElementByClass("labelinfo").Text
    ActiveCell.Value = driver.findElementsByClassName("labelinfo").Count  
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub FechaBrowser()
    driver.stop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to the specific element:

```
Dim oElementLooked as WebElement
set oElementLooked = driver.findElementsByClassName("labelinfo").Item(7)
```

If you wanted to loop over the responses, you could do something like:

```
Dim colNodes as WebElements
Dim oElementLooked as WebElement
set colNodes = driver.findElementsByClassName("labelinfo")
for each oElementLooked in colNodes
     ' Your code here
Next oElementLooked
```

Note that youd could also use item and a counter to loop.